# MongoDB connect 400 error message on postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongoDB using Node. Unfortunately, I use postman and got 400 error, While connection to MongoDB. my env file is exist:
DB_CONNECT = mongodb+srv://Hadar:******@cluster.r5qw9.mongodb.net/User?retryWrites=true&w=majority
Make sure the user and password both are correct.

[image]

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
//connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT,
() => console.log('connect to DB'))

app.use(express.json())

//import routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth')

//Router Middlewares
app.use('/api/user',authRoutes)
app.listen(5000, ()=>{console.log('Server is up and running')})
```

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../model/User')

router.post('/Login', async (req,res) =>{
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What you get in console, when starting server?

Comment: No error. connecting to server and connect to DB

Comment: It seems the error might be coming from the catch block of your request. Can you add a console to the catch block in your request handler `/Login`?

Comment: It enters to catch block. It said name and password are required but I provide them in postman . you can see in the first picture of my post

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/Login', async (req,res) =>{
  try{
    const user = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      password: req.body.password
    });
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send(savedUser);
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
}
```

Change your code with above, problem can be related with `trycatch` block

Comment: didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
In postman:

```
Content-Length : <calculated when request is sent>
```

This header was present by default (along with 5 others) which I have disabled. Enable this and you'll receive the request body.